# @Override problems with ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to reimport my projects which use the ViewPagerIndicator library project, but eclipse tells me that there are a lot of "@Override" notations wrong in the vpi project. On another PC, it works fine with the same code.

Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Change java Compiler to 1.6 it lower than 1.6.so prblm...
```

**Right Click on your project -->proprties -->Java Compiler-->Check Enable project spefic settings-->Compile Compilence level -> 1.6**