# Android - need assistance with basic syntax

Tags: android

I have some code to create a basic dialog box with several options - if i select a certain option, i get a message saying this has been clicked - i know very basic stuff.

This is my code:

The public method - public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) returns an error stating that it must override a superclass method.

Can anyone tell me what this superclass method is? I can't seem to find it anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Chilun

```
package net.learn2develop.Dialog2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CharSequence[] items = { "Google", "Apple", "Microsoft" };
    boolean[] itemsChecked = new boolean [items.length];

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new
                DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    })
    .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        **public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked)** {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!" : " unchecked!"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                        }
                    }
        )
        .create();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775946/override-problems-with-viewpagerindicator/9775978#9775978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks OK. Check your project properties and see if your project compliance is 1.6. Right click your project -> `Properties` -> Under the `Java Compiler` -> `Compiler compliance should be set to 1.6`. Java 1.5 doesn't allow the `@Override` annotation use there.